# ASP.NET Dynamic Data 4: QueryableFilterRepeater retrieve key-value pair

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Dynamic Data 4. I can't understand how can I retrieve key-value pair of automatic generate filter in this control. I need to create a query string URL.

Comment: If you main purpose is to create a query string URL for Insert.aspx page you may try to implement the following technique: http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/01/getting-default-values-from-list-page.html

Comment: I saw this tutorial but it talk about the using of control FilterRepeater that is deprecated (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.dynamicdata.filterrepeater.aspx). I need exactly of the same thing but with QueryableFilterRepeater

Comment: OK. I understand you. Well, try the following method in order to be able to insert data with default values from filters: http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/01/getting-default-values-from-list-page.html. It allows you to deal with `QueryableFilterRepeater`. It is  very nice approach and works great in my project!

Comment: Shortly this way allows to store the filters value in `Session` state and then you can get navigate url for `Insert.aspx` page with filter values in query string.

Comment: Very complex for simple get value from a control!! I abandoned this control and all written by hand.

Comment: Oh, i am sorry, i have repeated the link from my first comment. Actually, i would like to post http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2010/12/filter-history-for-dynamic-data-4.html.